# AngularJS Securing Service values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security

1. In my angularJS application when user logs in his roles are stored in a loginService, but I have found that those values are editable by user through console.
   How can I secure that?
2. What about CSRF handling?

I have many other security concerns with my angular/easyREST application, any useful link is very appreciated.

Comment: Why does it matter that the user can change the values? Remember, you can never trust external data (from users or other services).

Comment: server side validations are important and there is no doubt about it.
but in client side I store something like roles. lets say user does not have the role to view something, if he can change his role he will be able to view that (until he refreshes the page).

Comment: That's one of the drawbacks of doing more application logic on the client side, you could of course separate the user/admin role views. But is it worth it? Even if a user changed his role to admin, and got admin controls (edit, delete, etc), the server side validation should kick in and deny access to those methods.

Comment: If that "something" is static and the source is available, nothing would prevent an apt *attacker* from accessing it anyway. If it is dynamic, as in "a response from your server to a request" then you're again at the point to not trust client data (here: roles).

Comment: So it's better to get the user's roles from server anytime he wants to do something sensitive...

Comment: I don't think this would achieve anything. The idea is to keep track of the user roles on the server separately. And anytime the user submits a request you deny or handle that request based on the server-side roles.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you worried only about editing stored values, you can make them private: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures 
I think it best you can do, but it will be possible to edit value if set breakpoint in function that have access to this value.
So you should use server-side checking anyway.

2) If you have user data in links, you should use $sanitize service before adding data to the page.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Comment: Thanks.
What about DOM manipulation? like adding another <option> to a <select> ?

Comment: Let's say I have a select in my HTML which is populated with an AJAX call , after that my select will have two options. How can I prevent user from creating another option (like with firebug or something)?

Comment: You can't, as long as it's in the browser the user can change it. You will have to use server side validation to ensure that you get valid data from the user.